# Why constants are not recommended in the class of ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, module, constants

It seems that it is a protocol to write a class this way when you have some constants to add:

```
module AddressValidator
  FIELD_NAMES = [:street, :city, :region, :postal_code, :country]
  VALID_VALUE = /^[A-Za-z0-9\.\# ]+$/
  class << self
    ...
  end
end
```

To add constants in the class also work, but why it is not recommended?

```
class AddressValidator
  FIELD_NAMES = [:street, :city, :region, :postal_code, :country]
  VALID_VALUE = /^[A-Za-z0-9\.\# ]+$/

  ...
end
```

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: Who told you that such a rule exists?

Comment: Your first example doesn't create a class, it creates a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be a bit confused.

The first example you have does not create a class.

```
class << self
```

This is the notation for opening the singleton class of the current object in scope (in the case of your example, the AddressValidator).

You can test this by calling `AddressValidator.new` and not getting an AddressValidator instance, but a `NoMethodError`.

I think what you may have heard is about **namespacing constants**, which does use Modules as a standard practice.

If you just have a bunch of constants that you want to separate with a namespace using a module like this is better than using a class. Basically, the rule of thumb is use modules for namespacing and classes only if you want to create instances of that class.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. In the first example, one can call a method defined inside the `class << self` like `AddressValidator.a_method`. So I got confused and I assumed that it creates a class.  But actually it is not because it cannot create an instance.